# Hide, Show, HIDE/SHOWALL buttons

Tags: jquery

***Heres the code:*** http://jsfiddle.net/t2nite/KCY8g/

I was creating these hiding boxes using jquery.

Each box has some text and a **"SHOW"** and **"HIDE"** button. I'm trying to create a **"SHOW/HIDE all"** button.

But when I tried the code at the bottom the whole button disappears.

```
$("#btn").toggle(function() {
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
});
```

This is the closest I can get to what I want.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").toggle(200);
});
```

The code on top works, but instead of hiding or showing all the boxes it just toggles them between hide and show. Help.

I only want the contents hidden and the buttons are not inside the para classes.

Comment: Do you want to hide all the boxes or hide their contents?

Comment: Is your button inside `.para2, .para3, .para4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through each element to check whether they are hidden or not. It really depends on whether you want to first hide them all or show them all. Here is what you need:

```
// To toggle each element's state
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").each(function (index, element) {
       if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
           $(this).hide(200);
       } else {
           $(this).show(200);
       }
   });
});

// To show all and hide all afterwards or vice-versa (change the attr check)
$("#btn").click(function() {
   if ($(this).attr('data-show')) {
       $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
       $(this).attr('data-show', false);
   } else {
       $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
       $(this).attr('data-show', true);
   }
});

// To hide all if one is shown
$("#btn").click(function() {
   var oneShown = false;
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").each(function (index, element) {
       if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
           oneShown = true;
       }
   });
   if (oneShown) {
       $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
   } else {
       $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use both callbacks in the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) **event**:

```
$("#btn").toggle(function() {
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
}, function() {
   $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/CDEMS/

I'm assuming that's what you were trying to toggle like?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
$("#btn").data('tgl','hide').click(function() {
   if ($(this).data('tgl') == 'hide') {
      $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
      $(this).data('tgl','show');
   } else {
      $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
      $(this).data('tgl','hide');
   }
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/KCY8g/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to use classes rather than elements with specific IDs, so you could make this behavior-based (thus requiring less code and making it easier to add or remove `itsawrap` elements).

HTML:

```
<div id="showall"><button id="btn">HIDE/SHOW ALL</button></div>


<div class="itsawrap">
    <button class="hide">HIDE</button>
    <button class="show">SHOW</button>
    <p class="para2">"Who you callin' pinhead?"</p>
    <p id="btm" class="para2">- Patrick Star</p>
</div>

<div class="itsawrap">
    <button class="hide">HIDE</button>
    <button class="show">SHOW</button>
    <p class="para3">"He was a good man, what a rotten way to die."</p>
    <p id="btm" class="para3">- JC Denton</p>
</div>

<div class="itsawrap">
    <button class="hide">HIDE</button>
    <button class="show">SHOW</button>
    <p class="para4">"Wooooooooo!!"</p>
    <p id="btm" class="para4">- Ric Flair</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn")
    .data('shown', true)
    .click(function() {
    var mode = $(this).data('shown') ? 'hide' : 'show';
    $('.itsawrap p')[mode](200);
    $(this).data('shown', mode == 'show');
});

$('.itsawrap').on('click', '.hide', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('p').hide(200);
}).on('click', '.show', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('p').show(200);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TsUDV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

All of your code can be condensed into three events here.. Try this approach..

```
$("#btn").toggle(function() {
    $(".para2, .para3, .para4").hide(200);
}, function() {
    $(".para2, .para3, .para4").show(200);
});

$("[id^='hide']").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('p').hide(200);
});

$("[id^='show']").click(function() {
   $(this).closest('div').find('p').show(200);
    $('.itsawrap').not($(this).closest('div')).find('p').hide(200);
});
```

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KCY8g/6/)**